# Error: Can not install PostgreSQL 9.5.11 on Windows 10 machine

Tags: postgresql, installation, enterprisedb

So, I came across the same issue as posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46118851/unable-to-install-postgresql-on-windows-10), BUT my error log says something different (see below, please). I have been trying to install PostgreSQL 9.5.11 on Windows 10 (x64) using Enterprise DB interactive installer. But, no success (I am aware about the BigSQL installers but I prefer the Enterprise DB one :)).

I googled already and tried the suggested solutions [here](http://1stopit.blogspot.dk/2011/01/postgresql-83-and-84-fails-to-install.html), [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/230219/vbscript-wont-run-for-domain-user-on-windows-server-2008-r2) and [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/230219/vbscript-wont-run-for-domain-user-on-windows-server-2008-r2). However, no use. Can someone please help me to resolve this error?

Here is the lovely error message I am getting:

```
    Log started 04/17/2018 at 11:28:34
Preferred installation mode : qt
Trying to init installer in mode qt
Mode qt successfully initialized
Executing C:\my_user\AppData\Local\Temp/postgresql_installer_676baef523/temp_check_comspec.bat 
Script exit code: 0

Script output:
 "test ok"

Script stderr:


Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-x64-9.5 Data Directory. Setting variable iDataDirectory to empty value
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-x64-9.5 Base Directory. Setting variable iBaseDirectory to empty value
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-x64-9.5 Service ID. Setting variable iServiceName to empty value
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-x64-9.5 Service Account. Setting variable iServiceAccount to empty value
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-x64-9.5 Super User. Setting variable iSuperuser to empty value
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-x64-9.5 Branding. Setting variable iBranding to empty value
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-x64-9.5 Version. Setting variable brandingVer to empty value
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-x64-9.5 Shortcuts. Setting variable iShortcut to empty value
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-x64-9.5 DisableStackBuilder. Setting variable iDisableStackBuilder to empty value
[11:28:39] Existing base directory: 
[11:28:39] Existing data directory: 
[11:28:39] Using branding: PostgreSQL 9.5
[11:28:39] Using Super User: postgres and Service Account: NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService
[11:28:39] Using Service Name: postgresql-x64-9.5
Executing cscript //NoLogo "C:\my_user\AppData\Local\Temp\postgresql_installer_676baef523\prerun_checks.vbs"
Script exit code: 1

Script output:
 CScript Error: Loading script "C:\my_user\AppData\Local\Temp\postgresql_installer_676baef523\prerun_checks.vbs" failed (Access is denied. ).

Script stderr:
 Program ended with an error exit code

Error running cscript //NoLogo "C:\my_user\AppData\Local\Temp\postgresql_installer_676baef523\prerun_checks.vbs": Program ended with an error exit code
```

Comment: same problem: https://superuser.com/questions/1351383/unable-to-install-postgresql-on-win10-due-to-getlocales-exe